# P-value Test For Hypothesis

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing, p-value

I am working on the following question:

> For a two-sided t-test to test $H_0: \mu = 6.5$ versus $H_1: \mu \neq 6.5$, based on a sample of size $n$, the test statistic value is $-2.16$ and the $p$-value is $0.026$. Then the p-value for the t-test to test $H_0: \mu = 6.5$ versus $H_1: \mu > 6.5$, based on the same sample, is
>
> A. 0.974
>
> B. 0.026
>
> C. 0.013
>
> D. 0.987
>
> E. None of the Above

The answer to the question in the book is showing as 0.987
However, I don't understand how this is the correct answer. Given that the test statistic is 2.16, for a one sided test, the p-value would be given by the following:

$1-P(Z<2.16)$

From a normal distribution table, this comes as $1-0.9846$ which is $0.0154$

So shouldn't the answer be none of the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The stated answer of D is indeed correct.

To see why, you have to look carefully at the relationship between the test statistic, which is $t = -2.16$, and the new alternative hypothesis, which is $H_1: \mu > 6.5$. I'll use this diagram from [Tests of Hypotheses Based on a Single Sample](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4614-0391-3_9) by Devore and Berk as a guide:

[image]

The p-value given to you is one calculated with picture 3, i.e. a two-tailed test. This is saying that the total area captured in the sum of both tails beyond the test statistic is $0.026$ -- or in other words, that $0.013$ of the area is to the left of the stated test statistic of $t = -2.16$, and another $0.013$ of the area is to the right of its mirror image, $t = 2.16$.

Since the alternative hypothesis has the structure $H_1: \mu > 6.5$, that means your job is to shade an area to the *right* of something, as shown in situation 1 above. What's different, though, is that your test statistic is negative, meaning that the vertical bar should actually be drawn to the *left* of $t = 0$ on the curve. That means that when you shade an area, you're actually going to shade *most* of the area under the curve. We already established above that the amount of area to the left of the test statistic was $0.013$, which means that the area to the right of the test statistic is $1 - 0.013 = \fbox{0.987}$.

**Why your answer isn't correct:** First, note that you shouldn't consult a table of normal values at all; you should consult a table of $t$-distribution values, because this is a $t$-test and not a $z$-test. Also, after making that switch, you should still be computing $1 - P(T < \color{red}{\mathbf{-}}2.16)$ to capture the area to the right of  $-2.16$.

**Why answer C isn't correct:** Because the stated alternative hypothesis is $H_1: \mu > 6.5$, not $H_1: \mu < 6.5$. Intuitively, this corresponds with expecting (before the experiment starts) for the sample to come out higher than the stated average (hence $H_1: \mu > 6.5$), but having the sample actually come out *lower* than the stated average (hence the negative test statistic).